# cursor: pointer inside or outside :hover

Tags: css

I have the following 2 css selectors:

```
.foo {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.foo:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

They both have the same functionality (I guess), but are there any performance differences between them? Which one is more "elegant" to use?

Comment: Please define "elegant". And any performance difference between those two rules would be insignificant.

Comment: Well, I know in current state of technology such a small change is insignificant, but I'd like to get more in-depth knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Mozilla Developer Network - Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)

The above linked documentation states a number of ***inelegant*** issues with the `:hover` pseudo-class.

> **Note**: The `:hover` pseudo-class presents major problems on touch screens. Depending on the browser, the :hover pseudo-class might never match, match only for a moment after touching an element, or continue to match even after the user has stopped touching and until the user touches another element. Web developers should make sure that content is accessible on devices with limited or non-existent hovering capabilities.

And:

> In IE8-11, hovering over an element and then scrolling up/down without moving the pointer will leave the element in `:hover` state until the pointer is moved. See [IE bug 926665](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedbackdetail/view/926665).

And:

> In IE9 (and possibly earlier), if a `<table>` has a parent with a non-auto `width` and `overflow-x: auto;`, and the `<table>` has enough content to horizontally overflow its parent and there are `:hover` styles set on elements within the table, then hovering over said elements will cause the `<table>`'s `height` to increase.

And:

> As of Safari Mobile for iOS 7.1.2, tapping a clickable element causes the element to enter the `:hover` state. The element will remain in the `:hover` state until a different element has entered the `:hover` state.

And, according to [sitepoint.com](https://www.sitepoint.com/10-ways-minimize-reflows-improve-performance/):

> ... the user can trigger reflows by activating a `:hover` effect ...

Although, [Google's Developer Article on Minimizing browser reflow](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow) doesn't explicitly mention `:hover`, it does state that:

> Sometimes reflowing a single element in the document may require reflowing its parent elements and also any elements which follow it.

And to:

> Minimize CSS rules, and remove unused CSS rules.
>
> If you make complex rendering changes such as animations, do so out of the flow. ...
>
> Avoid unnecessary complex CSS selectors ...

### My (somewhat educated) opinion

If you don't **need** it, don't include it.

Comment: Thank you very much. It really helped.

Comment: You're most welcome; thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's same. Just don't use this two times in `hover state` and `normal state`, it's useless.

Comment: I know it's the same, thats why I'd like know to know some more technical, in-depth details.